# Oracle how to drop type and its alter statements?

Tags: oracle

Below i mentioned oracle created type and it's altered varray limits. How i can drop these all statements?

```
create or replace 
    TYPE testname1 AS VARRAY(1) OF varchar2(255)
     ALTER TYPE testname1 MODIFY LIMIT 301
     ALTER TYPE testname1 MODIFY LIMIT 303
     ALTER TYPE testname1 MODIFY LIMIT 306
     ALTER TYPE testname1 MODIFY LIMIT 310
     ALTER TYPE testname1 MODIFY LIMIT 315
     ALTER TYPE testname1 MODIFY LIMIT 321
     ALTER TYPE testname1 MODIFY LIMIT 328
     ALTER TYPE testname1 MODIFY LIMIT 336
     ALTER TYPE testname1 MODIFY LIMIT 345
     ALTER TYPE testname1 MODIFY LIMIT 355
```

Comment: What do yoy mean with "drop a statement"? Do you mean "drop the type"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  that you need to drop the type, you may simply need:

```
DROP TYPE testname1
```